# How do i send DataSet's table /List of objects to client app?

Tags: c#, linq, list, ado.net, dataset

Hi to all good people out there.
My server c# app has a database stored in .sdf file. It loads data in dataset and then list of objects. It connects to c# client app through sockets.
Right now to send a table i do something like this: table -> tobytes -> socket -> totable.

Is there any way i could easily send a dataset's table/a list of objects to client app?
Or maybe a sql server is an answer? But my server app needs to do much more than just being a database.
Or it will just take way more time than simple "tobytes" and "totable" methods and i shouldnt even care?

Please, give me an adivice in wich way to dig :)

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET (a.k.a. ASMX web services) is very easy to set up on the server, and ASMX web services are very easy to connect to from a .NET client application.  You can write web services that return DataSets or lists of objects or whatever you like.

Comment: i got how to make it, but how do i insert it into my program?

Comment: You mean how can you get your client to subscribe to your webservice?

Comment: NO. Like i said, my server program cant be just a database. So i need this webservice to work inside my service program and send data which is an object of my server program. Otherwise it will be difficult to change data from the server program.

Comment: @Alena: huh? An ASMX webservice isn't just a database. Perhaps you mean that you want to be able to *push* data (and objects) from the server to each client, rather than waiting for the client to call the server to get the data?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio you could use the [Web Service Software Factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699490.aspx) 
That way you can create an ASMX or WCF Service, includes designing your service with diagrams, so that you only need to code the business logic, and it's pretty easy to connect to a service that way (just check that you download the right version for your IDE)